# 19.10:& 18.04: Charger plug, unplug not detected promptly: Windows sees change promptly

Tags: power-management, laptop, lenovo, battery, acpi

It has ended up with a ticket to kernel bugzilla: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206731

I have a [Lenovo Ideapad 330-17ICH](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-300-series/Lenovo-ideapad-330-17ICH/p/88IP3001011) laptop running Ubuntu 19.10. Since I've installed Ubuntu I'm having issues with charger - it's not recognized instantaneously. After a while after connected (probably when battery level changes) , it's recognized as "charging". The same is in reverse way - after a while it notices that charger was unplugged. I've tried Ubuntu 18.04, Linux Mint etc and on each I have the same problem. I've tried Windows for a second and there charger is recognized instantaneously.

Currently, instead of swapping over different systems distros I'm trying to fix this problem here, on Ubuntu.

The very first thing I've tried is to install another kernels - I've tried 4.14 (as there are some incompatibilities on 4.15 - 4.19 with my laptop), 5.5.4 and now running on 5.3.0. On each of them I have same similar.

Here are the logs:

- I've grepped over the boot logs for ACPI, and here's the [result](https://gist.github.com/Dominos/dcd6eb0daf24e4dbb44e5b3dee3b7620) containing ACPI:
- And here's [full syslog](https://gist.github.com/Dominos/23e658b41fe90b7b08c172533b4b08e5) just from boot:
- The command `grep . /sys/class/power_supply/*/*` [output](https://gist.github.com/Dominos/5ef9252a94c4a8805682eede87b73ec1#file-gistfile1-txt)
- [dmesg](https://gist.github.com/Dominos/a2665146a4af228c97f74e1563ec8b7d#file-dmesg-txt)
- [acpidump](https://gist.github.com/Dominos/41ade2cf5ea12a4a4db3aa730e1a85e5#file-acpidump_ideapad_330_17ich_ubuntu-txt)

From all of that, those logs seems to be pretty meaningful:

```
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344417] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): 
Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20191018/dswload2-323)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344436] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20191018/psobject-220)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344441] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344501] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01], AE_NOT_FOUND (20191018/dswload2-159)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344508] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20191018/psobject-220)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344512] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344541] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20191018/dswload2-159)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344547] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20191018/psobject-220)
Feb 19 19:48:24 domin kernel: [    0.344551] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
```

but Google search results say it's all about too new hardware.

Do you have any ideas where can I look further?

EDIT1: I've upgraded Bios to the latest version - no changes occurred
EDIT2: added dmesg, acpidump and result of `grep . /sys/class/power_supply/*/*`

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `grep . /sys/class/power_supply/*/*` and the `dmesg` output after that?

Comment: The output of `acpidump` may be useful too.

Comment: ACPI tables! Is it a good idea do dump acpitables from Windows and import them on Ubuntu? @AlexandreTeles I've updated the post with outputs.

Comment: You could try, but I honestly can't see anything wrong with battery management in your dumps. It's either something with the Ubuntu's kernel compilation/version or with the Kernel itself. This isn't the first problem of that kind I see and you can find problems like https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44161 present in the kernel for literally years. I would probably open a ticket on Ubuntu and the kernel bug tracking systems with those logs.

Comment: ok I'm going ahead and it will end up with a ticket to both kernel tracking system and Ubuntu. I've talked to a friend who has simiar hardware and he has the same problem when he installed Ubuntu

Comment: If you can, link your tickets as comments here so people with the same problem can follow it.

Comment: I've just updated a post with the issue on issuetracker