# How to import ACPI tables from a dump?

Tags: power-management, acpi

I've recently wrote a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211638/19-10-18-04-charger-plug-unplug-not-detected-promptly-windows-sees-change-p) about charger (un)plug not detected promptly, which has ended up with a ticket to bugzilla.

In order to try to fix up my issue, I decided to dump ACPI tables from Windows - where it all works just fine. I made a dump using [RWEverything tool](http://rweverything.com/), then scanned on Ubuntu using `fwts`. Dump was scanned successfully, so I can claim it is fine.
Now I'm a bit stuck, because I don't know how should I import this dump on Ubuntu.
Each table in `sys/firmware/acpi/tables` looks in this format (example with DSDT):

```
    DSDT<95><E8>^B^@^B<91>LENOVOCB-01   ^A^@^@^@ACPI^@^@^D^@<A0>O<B9>^@^ULHIH^@^@^ULLOW^@^@^UIGDS^@^@^ULIDS
^@^@^UBRTL^@^@^UALSE^@^@^UGSMI^@^@^U\/^C_SB_PCI0GFX0^F^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0GFX0ALSI^@^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0GFX0CDCK
^@^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0GFX0CBLV^@^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0GFX0GSSE^@^@^U\/^C_SB_PCI0IPU0^F^@^U\/^C_SB_PCI0PEG0^F^@^U\/
^D_SB_PCI0PEG0PEGP^F^@^U\/^C_SB_PCI0PEG1^F^@^U\/^C_SB_PCI0PEG2^F^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0GFX0DD1F^F^@^U\/^D_SB_PC
I0GFX0GLI^A^U\/^D_SB_PCI0GFX0GSC^@^U\._SB_PR00^F^@^U\/^C_SB_PR00LPSS^D^@^U\/^C_SB_PR00TPSS^D^@^U\._SB_CP
PC^A^@^U\._TZ_TZ00^F^@^U\._TZ_ETMD^A^@^UM64B^@^@^UM64L^@^@^UM32B^@^@^UM32L^@^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0XHC_PS0^@^U\
/^D_SB_PCI0XHC_PS3^@^U\/^E_SB_PCI0XHC_RHUBPS0^@^U\/^E_SB_PCI0XHC_RHUBPS2^@^U\/^E_SB_PCI0XHC_RHUBPS3^@^U\
/^E_SB_PCI0XHC_RHUBINI^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0XDCIPS0^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0XDCIPS3^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0HDASPS0^@^U\/^D_SB_P
CI0HDASPS3^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0HDASPPM^A^U\._SB_VMO^@^U\._SB_VMO^@^U\/^C_SB_PCI0HID^D^U\/^C_SB_PCI0HIW^A^U\/
^D_SB_PCI0SAT0SAT^A^U\/^D_SB_PCI0SAT0SAT^D^U\/^D_SB_PCI0RP05PON^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0RP05POF^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0RP
07PON^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0RP07POF^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0RP09PON^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0RP09POF^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI0RP11PON^@^U\/
^D_SB_PCI0RP11POF^@^U\/^D_SB_PCI
...
```

while my dump looks in human-readable format:

```
Signature       "DSDT"
Length  0x0002E895 (190613)
Revision        0x02 (2)
Checksum        0x91 (145)
OEM ID  "LENOVO"
OEM Table ID    "CB-01   "
OEM Revision    0x00000001 (1)
Creator ID      "ACPI"
Creator Revision        0x00040000 (262144)
DefinitionBlock ("DSDT.AML", "DSDT", 0x02, "LENOVO", "CB-01   ", 0x00000001)
{
        If(Zero)
        {
                External(LHIH, 0x00, 0x00)
                External(LLOW, 0x00, 0x00)
                External(IGDS, 0x00, 0x00)
                External(LIDS, 0x00, 0x00)
                External(BRTL, 0x00, 0x00)
      ...
```

Plus all tables in a dump I have in one file.

So, my question is: can I somehow import this dump to Ubuntu? If so, how do I do this?
What's the exact difference between those dumps formats?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `iasl -d DSDT` is what you want?